# Is there an Kotlin equivalent `with` function in Swift?

Tags: swift, kotlin

In Kotlin, we could change the below

```
// Original code
var commonObj = ClassCommonObj()
 commonObj.data1 = dataA
 commonObj.data2 = dataB
 commonObj.data3 = dataC

// Improved code
var commonObj = ClassCommonObj()
with(commonObj) {
    data1 = dataA
    data2 = dataB
    data3 = dataC
}
```

However in Swift as below, do I have equivalent `with` function to use?

```
// Original code
var commonObj = ClassCommonObj()
 commonObj.data1 = dataA
 commonObj.data2 = dataB
 commonObj.data3 = dataC
```

Comment: Not developed yet...

Comment: No buddy there is no function like this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, no such functionality so far in Swift. However, similar functionality can be reached with the power of extensions:

```
protocol ScopeFunc {}
extension ScopeFunc {
    @inline(__always) func apply(block: (Self) -> ()) -> Self {
        block(self)
        return self
    }
    @inline(__always) func with<R>(block: (Self) -> R) -> R {
        return block(self)
    }
}
```

This protocol and extension provides two `inline` functions, where one can be served to return processed object, and the other is strictly similar to `with` in Kotlin and other languages (Visual Basic supported in 90s).

**Usage**

Specify types which these functions should apply to:

```
extension NSObject: ScopeFunc {}
```

**`apply`**:

```
let imageView = UIImageView().apply {
    $0.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    $0.isOpaque = true
}
```

Here we create an object and once the closure is executed, modified object is returned.

**`with`**:

```
imageView.with {
    $0.isHidden = true
}
```

Works equal to `with` in Kotlin.

Originaly based on [this source code](https://gist.github.com/kakajika/0bb3fd14f4afd5e5c2ec).

**NOTE:**

Swift compiler is generally regarded as smart enough to decide whether or not a function should be inlined. Quite likely, these two would be inlined due to their relative compactness even without strictly specifying `@inline (__always)`. Either way, you should know that this keyword does not affect the logic and the result of these, because inlining is about [optimizing the program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function).

Comment: I'd add `@discardableResult` for those functions to save some nerves. But it must be described in detail, because not everybody knows about this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Like [@Hexfire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4634527/hexfire) said, so far, no built-in Swift equivalent to Kotlin's `with()`. As he points out, you can more or less write one yourself.

I use a version slightly different than the Kotlin `with()` that automatically returns the modified element (more akin to Kotlin's `apply`). I find this clearer, pithier, and more generally useful.

This is the version I use:

```
@discardableResult
public func with<T>(_ item: T, _ closure: (inout T) -> Void) -> T {
  var mutableItem = item
  closure(&mutableItem)
  return mutableItem
}
```

It's declared globally (so no dependency on `NSObject` or extension declarations). It also handles mutability like I expect. In use, it looks like:

```
let myWellDescribedLabel = with(UILabel()) {
  $0.attributedText = attributedStringTitle
  $0.isAccessibilityElement = true
  $0.numberOfLines = 1
}
```

Unfortunately (or is it? see comments), Swift does not have self syntax in closures, so you must reference the passed object as `$0` (or create a named parameter to the closure).

While we're here, a `withLet()` that handles optionals is also very useful:

```
@discardableResult
public func withLet<T>(_ item: Optional<T>, _ closure: (inout T) -> Void) -> Optional<T> {
  guard let item = item else { return nil }
  return with(item, closure)
}
```

These are in a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/claybridges/753c28b90e9a6c3cc55526617d9c53f2).

Comment: Actually, perhaps you should consider yoursef lucky that you have to write `$0` instead of just leaving it out completely. Of course it is an awfully powerful feature of Kotlin where the differences between keywords and self-defined functions start to blur; but just imagine: Constantly shifting `this` in deeply nested scopes make you often wonder where a particular function comes from. Unreadable with IDE support. Many programmers seem to consider this good practice.

Comment: Understood. I'm writing Kotlin now too, so I'll probably have the wisdom you speak inform my experience these next few months.