# Does swift have standard (scope) functions like in Kotlin?

Tags: swift, kotlin

In Kotlin we have a list of [standard (scope) functions](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Standard.kt#L35) (e.g. `let`, `apply`, `run`, etc)

Example of usage below

```
val str : String? = "123"
str?.let{ print(it) }
```

This makes the code looks more succinct without need to have `if (str != null)`

In swift, I code it as below

```
let str: String? = "123"
if str != nil { print(str!) }
```

I have to have `if str != nil`. Is there a `let` provided by default that I could use (without me writing my own)?

FYI, I'm new to Swift, and check around doesn't seems to find it.

Comment: Let me know why is tis a downvote question? I'm genuine in looking to see if there's such function, to learn the proper use of the language.

Comment: The answer to your inital question is "no." There are no methods in Swift which can be called on *any* object (compare e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/47586520/1187415). `Optional.map` comes close to it in your example, but unlike Kotlin's `let` , `map` is a method of some types (like Optional), but not a method on “any type.”

Comment: There's a blog on this https://medium.com/@elye.project/making-kotlin-scope-function-in-swift-ea694dafa059 showing what Swift could do and can't in term of scope function.

Answer (score 8):

if you like if, extend the functionality of Optional

```
extension Optional {
    func `let`(do: (Wrapped)->()) {
        guard let v = self else { return }
        `do`(v)
    }
}

var str: String? = "text"
str.let {
    print( $0 ) // prints `text`
}
str = nil

str.let {
    print( $0 ) // not executed if str == nil
}
```

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map with a different name?

Comment: this doesn't "transform" nothing like  the Optional.map does. In Your example it transforms to Void, so it is "masked" only. `public func map<U>(_ transform: (Wrapped) throws -> U) rethrows -> U?`

Comment: The `@escaping` seems to be unnecessary. If the intention is just to define a “restricted” version of map (without return value) then you could simply define it as ```func `let`(do: (Wrapped)->()) { map(`do`) }``` .

Comment: @MartinR, Yes, I am going to remove it, You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Optional.map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map) :

```
let str1 : String? = "123"
str1.map { print($0) }
```

prints `123`.

```
let str2 : String? = nil
str2.map { print($0) }
```

Doesn't print anything.

So if an optional is not `nil`, it is unwrapped and used as a parameter to the `map` closure. if not, the closure won't be called.

---

A more idiomatic approach in swift would be to use optional binding :

```
var str: String? = "123"
if let s = str { 
    print(s) 
}
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks @Carpsen90. By the way, why not `str?.map { print($0) }`

Comment: @Elye : `Optional.map` works on optionals. You would use optional chaining if you'd like to call `Collection.map` which doesn't work on optionals. In this case `str1?.map { print($0) }` would print each character in `str1` in a new line, since it's not the same `map` function

Comment: This technically achieves what the OP asked, but seems at odds with the intent (i.e. transforming values) and functional heritage of `map`. I wouldn’t personally advise this pattern...

Answer (score 2):

@user3441734's custom extension on `Optional`, and @ielyamani's use of `map(_:)` looks very different from scoping functions  in Kotlin;
their "equivalent" in Kotlin does **NOT** compile:
i.e. `nullableVar.let{...}` does not compile, it should have been `nullableVar?.let{...}`

Both the solutions are for `Optional` only, whereas Scoping functions in Kotlin works on non-null values (`Any?`).

---

#### Here is my solution for `T.let` and `T.also` in Swift

My solution is much closer the Kotlin's variants, though they still **don't** behave the same.

I have included tests below, please also read through them to make sure you see the differences.

```
import Foundation

/**
 Scope functions similar to those in Kotlin.
 Pay attention to IDE warnings as they hint improper usage of these functions, because they dont' behave the same as their Kotlin counterparts.
 */
protocol ScopingFunctionSupported{
    associatedtype ASelf = Self where ASelf:ScopingFunctionSupported

    func `let`<T>(block:(ASelf)->T) -> T
    func also(block: (ASelf)->Void) -> ASelf
}

extension ScopingFunctionSupported{
    @inline(__always)
    @discardableResult
    func `let`<T>(block:(Self)->T) -> T{
        return block(self)
    }
    
    @inline(__always)
    @discardableResult
    func also(block: (Self)->Void) -> Self{
        block(self)
        return self
    }
}

///`NSObject` is probably the closest to "Any?" in Kotlin; `AnyObject` cannot be extended.
extension NSObject: ScopingFunctionSupported{}
```

##### Test on `let`

```
func test_let(){
    var a: String? = nil
    print(a?.let{"Value of a is \($0)"} ?? "Value of a is nil")

    var b: String? = "B"
    print(b?.let{"Value of b is \($0)"} ?? "Value of b is nil")
    
    var c: String? = nil
    //Warning: Expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to 'Any'
    print(c?.let{"Value of c is \($0)"})
    
    var d: String? = "D"
    //This does not behave the same as its Kotlin "equivalent", returns optional variable!
    //Warning: Expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to 'Any'
    print(d?.let{"Value of d is \($0)"})
    
    var e: String = "E"
    print(e.let{"Value of e is \($0)"})
}
```

Output:

```
Value of a is nil
Value of b is B
nil
Optional("Value of d is D")
Value of e is E
```

##### Test on `also`

```
func test_also(){
    var a = "A".also{
        print("Assigning \($0) to a")
    }
    print("Value of a is \(a)")
    
    var x: String? = nil
    var b:NSString? = x?.also{
        print("Assigning \($0) to b")
    }
    //NSString...
    print("Value of b is \(String(describing: b))")
}
```

Output:

```
Assigning A to a
Value of a is A
Value of b is nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Swift way of doing the nil check

```
let str: String? = "123"
if let strUnwrapped = str { print(strUnwrapped) }
```

And if really want to ensure it is not nil, use `guard` (thanks @CouchDeveloper for pointing out)

```
let str: String? = "123"
guard let strUnwrapped = str else { return }
```

I know this didn't explicitly answer the question of having scoping function or not, but it provides me my original intent of finding the Swift way of checking nil or non nil I was looking for like the `let` of Kotlin being used.

Comment: "_the Swift way of doing the nil check_" - First and foremost, avoid Optionals whenever possible. "Doing it the right way" - that is unwrapping it, _should_ be performed with a `guard` or `if let`. IMHO idioms like this `str? = "abc"` or even this `str! = "abc"` may lead to issues, sooner or later.

Comment: Understood. The declaration above just to show a working code that illustrate if one received an `Optionals`. Agree that ideal world is not to use it as much.